# Laravel Tracking user activity

Tags: laravel, user-activity

Is there a way i can track a logged in user activity in Laravel without using any packages? I have tried using antonioribeiro/tracker package but doesn't have a clear read me manual. I want to know details like the pages visited by a user.
PS: For a small project i usually create a simple logPageHit() function that i place on the necessary Controller methods but right now am dealing with a big project

Comment: there are many ways if you try to write, or use online tracking systems like google and etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Log package with events,with example please follow this [link](https://github.com/spatie/activitylog)

**OR** Laravel Eloquent have many events for [manage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) it

Hope this work for you!!!

Comment: Thanks @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. However i am trying not to use any package.

Answer (score 1):

**Tracking If a User Is Currently Online**

You can create a Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware LastUserActivity
```

Inside the handle method, we need to add the following code:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
    Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
}
```

Go to App\Http\Kernel.php

add the above code, inside $middlewareGroups in the **web** section.

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity::class,
```

**Note:** It is important that it’s added after the StartSession middleware, otherwise, the Auth facade will not have access to the logged in user.

Go to App\User.php and add this method.

```
public function isOnline()
{
    return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

Now use this in any of your views.

```
@if($user->isOnline())
    user is online!!
@endif
```

Hope it helps. Read [this](https://erikbelusic.com/tracking-if-a-user-is-online-in-laravel/) tutorial for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. However this isn't what am exactly looking for. I realised maybe i was too broad so i have edited my question to be clearer.